# 2.8 Adaptive Subdivision

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, displacement

How can I enable adaptive subdivision in Blender 2.8? I have a noise texture plugged into the displacement output for a material, with the displacement method set to Displacement Only. There is no "adaptive" option for my subdivision surface modifier, however, when I increase the subdivision levels manually, the mesh is displaced in the rendered view.

I am rendering with cycles with the 2.8 beta version downloaded today.

Comment: Make sure you're in experimental mode!

Comment: How do I enable that in 2.8?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are the steps:

- Select Cycles for Render Engine
- Select Experimental for Feature Set
- Select Dicing Rate and Preview count in Subdivision drop down
- Select Subdivision Modifier from Modifiers tab but do not apply it
- Check Adaptive check box and choose dicing scale
- Done!

I hope that helps

[image: Demo Video]

Comment: Do NOT apply the modifier.

Comment: @L0Lock thanks. Forgot about that. Corrected the same.

Comment: How do I enable experimental mode in Blender 2.8?

Comment: The button is no longer in the same place it was in 2.79

Comment: Modified the answer. I'm also commenting because I'm not sure whether you get a notification whenever an answer is edited or not.

Comment: Also note: subdivision Adaptive is only available when this modifier is at the bottom of the stack!